# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBPermission

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, classnotfoundexception, maven-jetty-plugin, javax.comm

When I am trying to run Maven project on App Engine local Development Server .Its Show's some class Not found Exception

Given Below is my console Status

```
  Apr 7, 2014 11:56:01 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\new\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\web\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Apr 7, 2014 11:56:01 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\new\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\web\WEB-INF/web.xml
Apr 7, 2014 11:56:01 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'E:\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.0\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\new\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\web\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
Apr 7, 2014 11:56:04 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBPermission
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.initContext(JettyContainerService.java:172)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:299)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:79)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:97)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBPermission
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:299)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:288)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:287)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:391)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerClassLoader.loadClass(DevAppServerClassLoader.java:92)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:331)
    ... 15 more
```

Kindly input your Suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Support for JAX-B doesn't come around until Java SE 6.

1 Make sure an appropriate JAXB implementation is added to your classpath

2.Upgrade your JRE,to 1.6 or above

Comment: I am using the latest version of it.`Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 20:52:2
2+0530)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0-ea, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows xp", version: "5.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"` @Naveen

Comment: can you post pom.xml?